# Is it safe to delete a TFS Collection database after deleting collection?

Tags: tfs

On TFS 2013 I deleted some collections using

> TFSConfig Collection /delete /collectionName:[COLLECTION NAME]

and I noticed that, on SQL Server, the database Tfs_COLLECTIONNAME is not deleted.
Is it safe to delete it manually. If not what is the procedure to do the cleanup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As test step you may just take database to offline.

Anyway, you can not use this database in future: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfsconfig-cmd#collection

> You will not be able to re-attach the collection database to this or any other deployment.
>
> **Tip**: The /delete option will not delete the collection database from SQL Server. After deleting the collection database from TFS, you can delete the database manually from SQL Server.